# im using slick slider and the slide has issue in transition effect when it comes from last to first and first to last slider in infinite mode

Tags: html, jquery, slick.js

transition effect when it comes from last slide to first slide and first slide to last slide in infinite mode

```
$(".banner-slider").slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: "0px",
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  speed: 800,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  asNavFor: ".banner-text-slider",
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 992,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Can someone please help to resolve this animation issue